# <ul> problems using :nth-child to set different color

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have this `<ul>` and is trying to set a different color to the first, second, third and forth `<li>` title text. At this point only the fist elements color is applying. How can I fix this? This is my code:

```css
.ui-tabs-nav li a:nth-child(1n) {
  color: #EE843D !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li a:nth-child(2n) {
  color: #1FAC61 !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li a:nth-child(3n) {
  color: #ED707A !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li a:nth-child(4n) {
  color: #F9FFE8 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav" role="tablist">
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 4</a>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x60fq9yw/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `a` you have to put `nth-child` on `li` tag
[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x60fq9yw/2/)

```css
.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(1) a {
    color: #EE843D !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(2) a {
    color: #1FAC61 !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(3) a {
    color: #ED707A !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(4) a {
    color: #F9FFE8 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 4</a>
    <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes. To clarify, `:nth-child(2)` means "this element, when it's the second element in its parent". And all the <a>s are the first child in their parent <li>s.

Answer (score 1):

you should apply nth class in li because it won't work on a tag.

```css
.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(1n) a {
  color: #EE843D !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(2n) a {
  color: #1FAC61 !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(3n) a {
  color: #ED707A !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(4n) a {
  color: #F9FFE8 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav" role="tablist">
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 4</a>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using odd even for `nth-child`.

```css
.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(odd) a {
    color: #EE843D !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li:nth-child(even) a {
    color: #1FAC61 !important;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav" role="tablist">
        <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 4</a>
        <li><a href="#tab-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="luxe-icon " style="font-size:60pxpx; color:;"></i>Title 5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Use this even and odd.